# How to add description as part of schema metadata in BigQuery Views

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking a way how we can add description of fields to the views. In BQ UI there is no way to add description, its only for tables.

Is there way to do it programmatically using api's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for views to have field descriptions at present.  There's an [open feature request on our public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=137) to implement this.  You can star the issue to let us know it's something you're interested in and we'll prioritize accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

indirect way to provide description for fields in view is to provide good comments in `View's Query`. So then, when you go to `View's Details Panel` (vs `Schema`) you will see those comments/description in `Query Box` (below) `View Info` section.
Another option so far is to reuse `View's Description`  - this one is available in both UI and API.
Rather than that there is no support that I know of to individual filed's description for view